# TYPO3 Static File Cache - Cache-Control response header for JSON

Tags: json, .htaccess, caching, typo3

I want in the response headers `Cache-control: max-age=1800` for JSON. I am using Static File Cache. On local DDEV this works out of the box fine. For Mittwald - Apache server - I added the .htaccess rules as stated at the manual [1].

Typoscript:

```
jsonFeed = PAGE
jsonFeed {
    typeNum = 1234

    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        disableCharsetHeader = 1
        disablePrefixComment = 1
        additionalHeaders.10.header = Content-type: application/json
        admPanel = 0
        debug = 0
        no_cache = 0
        # this is also set in .htaccess
        cache_period = 1800
        sendCacheHeaders = 1
    }
    10 = USER
    10 {
        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
        vendorName = Bliep
        extensionName = Newsfeed
        pluginName = FeedList
        action = list
    }
}
```

I added extra in .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.json$">
   ForceType application/json
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

and

```
ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 1800 seconds"
```

On the first hit I indeed get response header `Cache-control: max-age=1800` with `X-Sfc-State: TYPO3 - add to cache`

On 2nd+ hit it always changes to `Cache-control: max-age=0` with indeed `X-Sfc-State: StaticFileCache - via htaccess`

I am not logged in the backend, and it also happens on another browser. Normal pages get correct cache-control. In local DDEV Ngninx I do get `Cache-control: max-age=1800` for https://bla.com/feed.json

feed.json is mapped in the routeEnhancer:

`feed.json: 1234`

Any clue what could cause this?

[1] https://docs.typo3.org/p/lochmueller/staticfilecache/main/en-us/Configuration/Htaccess.html.

Answer (score 0):

Static file chache works by creating "static files"

on your first request there is no file. so it apache will redirect to the index.php and then PHP will generate the file (write it to disk) and deliver it directly. so thats explains why the first request delivers the data correctly.

for the second request the file is there. and it gets delivered directly by the webserver. so your .htaccess modification does not seem to take the expected effect.

so the question becomes why does not apache not execute the FileMatch/header rule.

there are multiple reasons this might happen:

- rule order / another rule might prevent processing beforehand
- required modules are not loaded: Header and FilesMatch
- second rule which overwrites the first rule.

a good way to test if your rules get triggered ist to use a custom header (usally starting with "x-" for example "x-header-add: works")

Comment: I do not see any overwriting rules. When I put a JSON file in the fileadmin, the file gets properly served with `Cache-control: max-age=1800`. So it must be something related to the Static File Cache extension, maybe in combination with the RouteEnhancer.